# How to get the line length including newline when using Scanner?

Tags: go

I'm using `Scan` to scan lines 1 at a time from an IMAP connection, which are supposed to end with `\r\n`, but I suspect some of the lines I'm getting are actually ending in just `\n`, because I'm getting an incorrect amount of data when parsing the body atom in a particular instance

(`* 8620 FETCH (BODY[] {7060}` is what I'm getting for the body in just this one email, but that seems to be longer than the count if count newlines as 2 bytes)

```
// ...
r := bufio.NewScanner(d.conn)
for r.Scan() {
    line := r.Text()
    len(line) // gets the line length WITHOUT the newline
}
```

Would there be any way to get the length with the newline? Or get the length of the token that the scanner stopped with?

Comment: Never used go, but if the scanner is using either \r\n or \n to detect the end of line, you'll need to find a way to tell it you want the crlf or lf returning along with the other data it gives you, if that's even possible.. In the other langs I've used, when the data is delimited (eg in this case by \r\n or \n) you don't get the delimiter when you ask it to read the next chunk of delimited data. What problem with the length are you actually trying to solve? Why do you care if it's \r\n or \n ?

Comment: @CaiusJard I just added a bit more about what I'm trying to do. I'm talking to an IMAP server, and when I get to the body part, it returns an atom (brackets with the size of the following text, followed by the text), and the numbers don't match up. It's worked so far on ~50,000 emails, so I think this email might contain `\n` that the server didn't change to `\r\n`

Comment: ps; point to the scanning tag: *`scanning` - this tag should not be used for network, text or file scans*

Comment: @CaiusJard Oh whoops, I'll remove that

Comment: I wouldn't expect the server to modify the content of the email for \r\n vs \n might be a windows vs unix vs mac mail client.. If you're wondering if data is missing, try examining whether `bytes + (lines) = atom` or `bytes + (2*lines) = atom` - if neither, then bytes are missing?

Comment: @CaiusJard exactly the problem, this email's bytes doesn't match the atom size, which is a problem because there's no other way to tell where the atom ends if I can't get accurate counts regarding the type of newline used. Maybe I can get the scanner to scan forward a set number of bytes instead...

Comment: sounds like a job for tcpdump

Comment: I am not familiar with the imap protocotl, but if 7060 is a count of bytes, then you should slurp up that number of bytes instead of reading line by line.  Also, scanners buffer data.  If you create and discard scanners per body, you will discard buffered data.

Comment: @ThunderCat that's the route I've been attempting for the last few minutes, but I can't figure out how to do that in Go with their Scanner. There's an `advance` method on Scanners but it's not exported for some reason, so I can't call it from my code

Comment: bufio.Scanner is a high level API. Use [bufio.Reader](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader) for finer control, including the possibility to read N bytes (typically via [io.ReadFull](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadFull)).

Comment: @Peter looking through the doc this looks like the actual tool for the job. On a separate note, my suspicions were correct, this email was containing a mixture of crlf and lf

Comment: @BrianLeishman Don't use Scanner. It is only appropriate for reading delimited values (lines, words, etc), but that's not what you have.  As Peter mentioned, bufio.Reader is a better choice.  There are [serveral imap packages](https://godoc.org/?q=imap) for Go.  You might want to look at how the packages are implemented or possibly just use one.

Comment: @ThunderCat you are absolutely right, in fact, the bufio.Reader would actually solve some performance issues/other problems, too, so it definitely looks like the correct tool. While I found an answer to my literal question, I'll be changing my use to the Reader instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is an answer answers my question in the literal sense about including the `\n` and potential `\r`, using the Scanner in in the first place while reading an IMAP server's responses is NOT the correct tool, and I will be rewriting my use of the Scanner and replacing it with bufio.Reader.

---

You can specify custom split functions for use in your Scanner, so for example, you can port the ScanLines split function to one that doesn't drop the newline characters with the token that gets returned.

```
// ...
r := bufio.NewScanner(d.conn)
r.Split(func(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {
    if atEOF && len(data) == 0 {
        return 0, nil, nil
    }
    if i := bytes.IndexByte(data, '\n'); i >= 0 {
        // We have a full newline-terminated line.
        return i + 1, data[0 : i+1], nil
    }
    // If we're at EOF, we have a final, non-terminated line. Return it.
    if atEOF {
        return len(data), data, nil
    }
    // Request more data.
    return 0, nil, nil
})

for r.Scan() {
    line := r.Text()
    len(line) // now gets the line length WITH the newline
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default `SplitFunc` provided to `bufio.NewScanner` is `SplitLines` which includes a call to `dropCR` which, per the comments, matches on end-of-line `\r?\n`. Because the `Scanner` will optionally find and drop carriage returns, you won't be able to find the full length of a line using the `bufio.Scanner`.

From my experience, it's common to use the Scanner when things are basic, as it's a convenience struct. Otherwise bufio.Reader provides more flexibility. `bufio.Reader#ReadBytes(delim byte)` will give you what you're looking for.